# ListView filter not working on multiple columns Android

Tags: java, android, listview

I tried to filter my ListView searching for countries names, but because the ListView has multiple columns it doesn't filter it very well. Here is my code.

```
public class ShowGlobalStats extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
    TextView totalCases;
    DBInterface db;
    Context appContext;
    ArrayList<Stat> arrayStats = new ArrayList<Stat>();
    ListView lv;
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    StatsAdapter inflate;

    private DrawerLayout drawer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_countries_stats);
        giveValues();
        Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinnerFilter);
        final EditText countryFilter = findViewById(R.id.searchBar);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.filter,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        Toast.makeText(appContext, "You can click on each country to see detailed info!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        try {
            db.obre();
            Cursor c = db.obtainAllInformation();
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                Stat indiStat = new Stat(c.getString(0),
                        c.getString(1),
                        c.getInt(2),
                        c.getInt(3),
                        c.getInt(4));
                arrayStats.add(indiStat);
            }
            c.close();
            inflate(arrayStats);
            selectedCountry();
        } finally {
            retrieveGlobalInfo();
            db.tanca();
        }

        countryFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
                inflate.getFilter().filter(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
    }

    private void giveValues()
    {
        db = new DBInterface(this);
        appContext = this;
        totalCases = findViewById(R.id.totalCases);
        prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navView);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
    private void inflate(ArrayList<Stat> arrayStat) {
        inflate = new StatsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.inflate_all_info, arrayStat);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        lv.setDivider(null);
        lv.setDividerHeight(0);
        lv.setAdapter(inflate);
    }
```

Seems like this filtering method only supports one column, my ListView has 4, which are the Code of the country, the name of it, Cases and Deaths of COVID.

Trying to work on my APP as hard as possible to achieve my goal!

Comment: why are you using a ListView and not a RecyclerView?

Comment: I just did and it's all good now! Thanks for the advertise

Comment: note for the future, use a recyclerview, list views are outdated and not considered best practice